# Usage of "__add__" method in Tuple class

Tags: python, tuples

python noob here and playing around with the limitations of Tuples and Lists.

I don't have a problem, just a general query about usage of the `__methodname__` methods in the Tuple class and/or in general.

I am aware that you cannot modify Tuples and in order to do so, you have to convert it to a list, modify said list, then convert back to Tuple but I had a play around with the `__add__` method and found that it works. What are issues and limitations with using this to create new Tuples with modifications to an existing one?

CODE:

```
myTuple = ('item1', 2, 'item3', ['list1', 'list2'])
tupleModification = myTuple.__add__(('newTupleItem1','newTupleItem2'))
```

This outputs the following:

```
('item1', 2, 'item3', ['list1', 'list2'], 'newTupleItem1', 'newTupleItem2')
```

which is correct but i'm wondering if i'm playing with fire because I haven't seen this solution posted anywhere in relation to modifying Tuples.

EDIT: I am aware that you cannot modify existing Tuples and that this will create a new instance of one. I think I may have confused people with my naming conventions.

Comment: Compare `id(myTuple)` and `id(tupleModification)`

Comment: Since you implemented __add__ method, why won't you just do `myTuple + (('newTupleItem1','newTupleItem2')) ` isntead of `myTuple.__add__(('newTupleItem1','newTupleItem2'))`

Answer (score 9):

`__add__` is the method which is called when you do:

```py
myTuple + ("newTupleItem1", "newTupleItem2")
```

So this does not modify `myTuple` but creates a new `tuple` whose content is the content of `myTuple` concatenated with `("newTupleItem1", "newTupleItem2")`.

You can print `myTuple` to see that it has not been modified:

```
>>> myTuple
('item1', 2, 'item3', ['list1', 'list2'])
```

And you can check that `myTuple` and `tupleModification` are not the same object:

```
>>> myTuple is tupleModification
False
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify tuples, that's right. However, you can concatenate two existing tuples into a new tuple. This is done with the `+` operator, which in turn calls the `__add__` method. The resulting tuple will not be a "modification" of any of the original ones, but a new distinct tuple. This is what the code you posted does. More concisely, you can just do:

```
myTuple = ('item1', 2, 'item3', ['list1', 'list2'])
tupleModification = myTuple + ('newTupleItem1','newTupleItem2')
print(tupleModification)
# ('item1', 2, 'item3', ['list1', 'list2'], 'newTupleItem1', 'newTupleItem2')
```

EDIT: Just as a clarification, you cannot "edit" a tuple anyhow, that is, add or remove elements from it, or change its contents. However, if your tuple contains a mutable object, such as a list, then that inner object can be modified:

```
myTuple = (1, [2, 3])
myTuple[1].append(4)
print(myTuple)
# (1, [2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thank you... and I call them Truples because you can't change the Truth! :P

Comment: @AlphaBurger I have added a clarification with an example showing that, even when a tuple cannot be modified, inner mutable objects can.

Answer (score 3):

I think fundamentally you're confused about the difference between creating a new object with modifications (`__add__` in this case) and modifying an existing object (`extend` for example).

#### `__add__`

As other answers already mentioned, the `__add__` method implements the `+` operator, and it returns a new object. Tuples and lists each have one. For example:

```
>>> tuple_0 = (1,)
>>> tuple_1 = tuple_0.__add__((2,))
>>> tuple_1 is tuple_0
False
>>> 
>>> list_0 = [1]
>>> list_1 = list_0.__add__([2])
>>> list_1 is list_0
False
```

#### `extend`

Lists, which are mutable, have an `extend` method, which modifies the existing object and returns `None`. Tuples, which are immutable, don't. For example:

```
>>> list_2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id_save = id(list_2)
>>> list_2.extend([7])
>>> id(list_2) == id_save
True
>>> 
>>> tuple_2 = (4, 5, 6)
>>> tuple_2.extend([7])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

Lists have other methods which change the existing object, like `append`, `sort`, `pop`, etc, but `extend` is the most similar to `__add__`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between 1) modifying an existing tuple (in-place), and 2) leaving the original alone, but creating a new modified copy. These two different paradigms can be seen throughout computer programming, not just python tuples. For example, consider increment a number by one. You could modify the original, or you could leave the original alone, create a copy and then modify the copy.

```
MODIFYING IN-PLACE
BEFORE:
     x == 5
AFTER:
     x == 6

CREATING A MODIFIED COPY
BEFORE:
    x == 5
AFTER:
    x == 5 (unchanged)
    y == 6
```

`tuple.__add__` concatenates tuples. For example, `(x, y) + (a, b, c)` returns `(x, y, a, b, c)`

`tuple.__add__` does **not** modify the original tuples. It leaves the original tuples alone, and creates a new tuple which is the concatenation of the original two. This is contrast to something like `list.append` or `list.extend` which modifies the original list instead of returning a modified copy.

Tuple methods generally do the following:

1. copy the original
2. modify the copy in some way
3. leave the original alone.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm assuming that you can't modify an existing tuple (in-place) within python. Or is there some deeper level of programming where this is possible?

Comment: @AlphaBurger No existing tuple can be modified in-place within python. Tuples are "immutable." You can only create modified copies.